# Replace HTML button

Tags: xpath, odoo, odoo-10

Well, I have this button

[image: Payment button]

The problem is I need put a default context in my module but since V9 string xpath search was deprecated, that's good I think. But I need replace this button and the only name it has is this thing:

```
<button name="%(action_account_invoice_payment)d" type="action" states="open" string="Register Payment" groups="account.group_account_invoice" class="oe_highlight"/>
```

How the heck gonna replace this button if this has no name putting a context?

Sometimes this kind of things are not in the documentation and is very awful the no explanation from the code.

PS: I cannot alter the core code because I have a module for that :(

Comment: Not clear to me if you need an xpath expression to match this node. If yes : `'//button[contains(@name, "action_account_invoice_payment")]/@name'`

Comment: I tried, xml error. This button has no name, it calls a method but there's no documentation about this kind of implementation in Odoo10

Comment: try button[number_of _button] for xpath,
eg: button[2]